# Can't delete VM "Error: 'Error accessing storage"

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, disk

I can't delete a virtual machine, the following error appears

```
PS /home/azureuser> Remove-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName 'MyResourceGroupName' -DiskName 'MyDiskName' -Force
Remove-AzDisk: Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'Error accessing storage.'
ErrorCode: StorageFailure/LeaseIdMissing
ErrorMessage: Error accessing storage.
ErrorTarget: 
StartTime: 2/17/2024 7:04:52 AM
EndTime: 2/17/2024 7:04:52 AM
OperationID: 5cab0100-eb6b-4589-9eb8-acd1bc68fc30
Status: Failed
```

I have also tried to delete the disk associated with this virtual machine, the following error appears

```
PS /home/azureuser> Remove-AzVm -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -Name MyVirtualMachine -ForceDeletion $true  
Virtual machine removal operation
This cmdlet will remove the specified virtual machine. Do you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
Remove-AzVM: Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'Error accessing storage.  Target: '/subscriptions/dcfb3602-2c06-48a1-...........289b50f476c92b8c7d1479f74df'.'
ErrorCode: StorageFailure/LeaseIdMissing
ErrorMessage: Error accessing storage.  Target: '/subscriptions/dcfb3602-2c06-48a1-b3fe-76cae848ca0a/resourceGroups/...................b8c7d1479f74df'.
ErrorTarget: 
StartTime: 2/17/2024 7:08:37 AM
EndTime: 2/17/2024 7:09:38 AM
OperationID: b29e3d22-8290-403c-92da-6edca90f0cda
Status: Failed
```

Could you help me solve this problem please?

Thank you.

Run this commands via PS

```
Remove-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName 'MyResourceGroupName' -DiskName 'MyDiskName' -Force
```

```
Remove-AzVm -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -Name MyVirtualMachine -ForceDeletion $true
```

I was hoping to be able to delete the damn virtual machine, but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

The VM cannot be deleted because the storage cannot be deleted.

Something is stopping you from deleting the storage.

It could be several things:

- A process in the VM. Try stopping the VM before deleting it.
- Some other process that is accessing the same storage.
- Deployment script such as Terraform that is blocking the deletion
- There is a resource manager lock on the storage account

Comment: When stopping the VM the following error appears
"Failed to stop the virtual machine 'VM'. Error: Operation 'deallocate' is not allowed on VM 'VM' since the VM is marked for deletion. You can only retry the Delete operation (or wait for an ongoing one to complete).'"

For my part there is no process, I must add that I canceled the deployment of the VM while it was being created due to a name error.

Do not use Terraform.

I have checked the blocks and have not seen any at the subscription level.

Comment: It could be a lock that was added by the deployment process. Try: az lock list --resource-group <resource-group-name>

Comment: When I run az lock list --resource-group <resource-group-name>I don't get any results